# Godel Theorem proof in algorithm theory

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, incompleteness

I am currently reading the [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem explained by Vladimir A. Uspensky](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397594902224). And I came across the following theorem which I think has contradiction with itself. Since I am a physics student I have no grounding in Logic therefore I am asking for someone to explain to me if I am right or wrong.

> **Definition of the Problem:** *Let $\left<L,T\right>$ be a fundamental pair, let $\left<P, \bar P, \delta\right>$ be a deductive system over $L$, and let $Q$ be the set of all provable words. Suppose that $V\subseteq L^\infty$. We say that the deductive system $\left<P, \bar P, \delta\right>$ is:
> (A) Consistent relative to $V$ if $V\cap Q \subseteq V\cap T$ (B) Complete relative to $V$ is $V\cap T\subseteq V\cap Q$.*

The Theorem is then:

> **Theorem:** *Suppose that $V$ is an enumerable subset of $L^\infty$, and the set of true statements in $V$ is not enumerable. Then there is no deductive system which is both consistent and complete relative to $V$.*

The problem I am facing is that if a set $A$ is enumerable, which means that there exists a 1 to 1 resemblence for the set elements and the natural numbers, then how can $V$ be both enumerable and still have a subset (the set of true statements in $V$) that is not enumerable?

Comment: Maybe we have no algorithm (procedure) that, receiving as input the $n$-th element of enumerable set $V$, answer in a finite number of steps with Yes/No to the question: "is the formula True?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terminology issue; see the bottom of page $247$. Uspensky is using "enumerable" to mean "**computably enumerable**" (also called "recursively enumerable," "semidecidable," or "recognizable" - yeah, logic has a terminology problem), not "**countable**" (which is how you're reading it). Indeed, since the alphabet $L$ is assumed to be finite the whole set $L^\infty$ is countable, so every subset of $L^\infty$ is also countable.

Comment: I tried to go on with the theorem with considering the subset of true statements in $V$  being not enumerable while $V$ is. So let me see if I got it write, as an example Natural numbers are enumerable (computably enumerable) but the subset of prime numbers is not. although it is decidable. Is my view on it correct?

Comment: @KidA No, the set of prime numbers is computably enumerable. Note that decidability **implies** computable enumerability.

Comment: So I think I really don't understand these terminologies, is there anywhere I can look up for? I thought enumerable is the existence of a map between the set and natural numbers, decidability is existence of an algorithm that given an input $x$ returns true or false if $x\in S$ or $x\in S'$. I guess then the primes are enumrable. but I don't know how decidability imples computable enumerability.